# Having problems making a SUMO simulation work for omnet++

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

Trying to make my sumo simulation work on OMNeT++, but when modifying .launchd.xml i couldn't give permission to running sumo.
I'm currently using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, sumo 0.32.0, Veins 4.7.1 and OMNeT++ 5.3.
     I've searched for means to make a sumo simulation different from the erlangen example work. Until this point what I have found was modifying the `erlangen.launchd.xml` file to make it run my simulation and running

```
sudo python sumo-launchd.py -vv -c /home/gustavo/Downloads/sumo-0.32.0/bin/
```

However, everytime I tried to run it a message saying it lost connection appeared, so I tried creating a `poly.xml` archive with nothing in it (because I didn't want any buildings or something like that in the simulation) and it didn't work. I looked into the linux terminal and saw a message saying there was no `sumo.cfg` archive in the `sumo-0.32.0/bin` folder (I don't understand why it should, there is no `.sumo.cfg` archive from the erlangen example on that folder too), so I copied all the archives for the simulation (.net .rou .sumo.cfg and .poly) into the folder and tried again. This problem was solved but another error showed up in the terminal:

> Could not start SUMO (/home/gustavo/Downloads/sumo-0.32.0/bin/ -c simulation.sumo.cfg): [Errno 13] Permission denied

I tried running it the command with sudo but it didn't solved it. Does anyone know how to make it work or another way of making my own sumo simulation work in OMNeT++?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- debug config -->
<launch>
    <copy file="simulation.net.xml" />
    <copy file="simulation.rou.xml" />
    <copy file="simulation.poly.xml" />
    <copy file="simulation.sumo.cfg" type="config" />
</launch>
```

I hoped to make my sumo simulation work on OMNeT++ because any other website that I looked didn't show that problem.

Comment: sorry for the way the site made my question look like i'm not a potato behind a keyboard

Answer (score 1):

The parameter -c for the sumo-launchd expects the full path to the executable so you need to include sumo at the end:

```
sudo python sumo-launchd.py -vv -c /home/gustavo/Downloads/sumo-0.32.0/bin/sumo
```

Comment: I tried removing the -c part and everything that comes next and it worked but i think your solution might work. Thank you very much.